# Javascript code inside HTML code inside PHP string

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, preg-replace

Trying to write a string in PHP. The string contains HTML code. The HTML code contains Javascript code inside it. And all that in a PHP string.

Current Code:

```
$record["DESCRIPTION"] = preg_replace("/(<iframe.*<\/iframe>)/U",
'$1 <br> 
<button type="button" onclick="download()">تحميل</button><script>function download() {
APP.CallSub("download", true, YouTubeGetID($1));}
 function YouTubeGetID(url){ 
 var ID = "";  url = url.replace(/(>|<)/gi,"").split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);  if(url[2] !== undefined) {    ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);    ID = ID[0];  }  else {    ID = url;  }    return ID;}
</script>', $record["DESCRIPTION"]);
```

The problem is in calling the function `YouTubeGetID()`. I want to call this function with the PHP regex result `"$1"` as a parameter. I tried:
* `YouTubeGetID($1)`
* `YouTubeGetID("$1")`

Both did not work. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

PS: the `YouTubeGetID()` function is working properly. I tested it with a normal string `YouTubeGetID("https://youtube.com/watch?v=tN_dtNinTjk")`. The problem is using the regex result $1 instead of any string.

Comment: Did you try swapping all " for ' and use "$1......", $record

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Your code is quite a mess. Maybe formatting it helps you to understand it better.

Comment: @Toto Hi, isn't   "("   and   ")"   before and after the iframe tags a capturing and $1 means the iframe tag ?

Comment: are you trying to capture the URL (i.e. via the *src* attribute) of the iframe?

Comment: @SamOnela in the regex replace im trying to capture the iframe tags from the htlm page code. in the "youtubegetid" function it capture the if of the video not the url

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen it. I remove my comment.

Comment: @mplungjan  i did not understand bro, what do you mean by "$1......" ?

Comment: You have single quotes `'$1 <br> .."` - it might work better with `"$1 <br> ...." since PHP reacts differently when it expands variables inside "$x" and '$x' - so to have double quotes you need to first change all double quotes inside the script to single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working. Here is a formatted version of it. I run it on a [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) without any problem. The only adjustment was to change the greedy selector `.*` to a non-greedy one `.*?`.

I'm guessing, your generated JavaScript code is the problem here. The generated JavaScript code is not valid. You need to escape everything in `$1` and surround it with brackets.

Here is a formatted version of your code.

```
<?php
    $record = array("DESCRIPTION" => '<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>');

    $replacement = '$1<br>';
    $replacement .= '<button type="button" onclick="download()">تحميل</button>';
    $replacement .= '<script>';
    $replacement .= 'function download() {';
    $replacement .= '   APP.CallSub("download", true, YouTubeGetID($1));';
    $replacement .= '}';
    $replacement .= 'function YouTubeGetID(url){';
    $replacement .= '   var ID = "";';
    $replacement .= '   url = url.replace(/(>|<)/gi,"").split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);';
    $replacement .= '   if(url[2] !== undefined) {';
    $replacement .= '       ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);';
    $replacement .= '       ID = ID[0];';
    $replacement .= '   } else {';
    $replacement .= '       ID = url,';
    $replacement .= '   }';
    $replacement .= '   return ID;';
    $replacement .= '}';
    $replacement .= '</script>';

    $record["DESCRIPTION"] = preg_replace("/(<iframe.*?<\/iframe>)/U", $replacement, $record["DESCRIPTION"]);

    echo $record["DESCRIPTION"];
?>
```

And here is the output of this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe><br><button type="button" onclick="download()">تحميل</button><script>function download() { APP.CallSub("download", true, YouTubeGetID(<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>));}function YouTubeGetID(url){ var ID = "";    url = url.replace(/(>|<)/gi,"").split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/); if(url[2] !== undefined) {      ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);     ID = ID[0]; } else {        ID = url,   }   return ID;}</script>
```

---

If you need further help, please provide a comment below.

Comment: for some reason your code did not worked for me, the javascript on the did not executed successfully
i ended up saving the data in an html attribute tag then getting it from javascript.

thanks a lot